# Xcode build works for simulator but not device

Tags: ios, xcode, build-error, xcode8.2

I have looked everywhere and done everything which was given but there is still one error which is not given anywhere. I have Xcode version 8.2beta and Unity version 5.5.2. The project build works for simulator, but when I build for device, this error is generated

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_UnityRate_sendToRate", referenced from:
      _UnityRate_UnityRate_sendToRate_m3793811931 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
      _UnityRate_SendToRating_m1702357742 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_5.o
     (maybe you meant: _UnityRate_UnityRate_sendToRate_m3793811931)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Why you don't try to use the last Xcode 8.3.3? You are using an old beta version where some issue are possible.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I found error in the code, as I was using some script which was give this error, I did thorough reading of what was going on the script called unityrate found something unusual  and corrected it that my problem is solved.